# How to display a number with many decimal places? (Java)

Tags: java, numbers, double, decimal, pi

I was wondering if there is a way to "cheat" and work with numbers with way more decimal places than a double in Java, and then display it via `[Graphics Object].drawString(number, 10, 10);`

Can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the BigDecimal class.

http://download.oracle.com/javase/1,5.0/docs/api/java/math/BigDecimal.html

Comment: does it support decimals with over 100 digits beyond the decimal point?

Comment: @JavaCoder-1337 yes, see the Javadoc.

Comment: It won't let me set a value to the BigDecimal variable. I want a BigDecimal, but it says that I am trying to make a double (on one side) a BigDecimal. I tried casting to BigDecimal, but it won't work.